# Replace CASE WHEN statement with something more sensible

Tags: sql, sql-server

While checking my SPs today I found that I have,

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(MP.NewPrice, MP.Price, 2147483647)),0) = 2147483647 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(MP.NewPrice, MP.Price, 2147483647)), 0) END
FROM    MerchantsProducts MP
```

I need to replace this with something which make more sense. Can someone please review this?

Comment: What is the intended effect of this SQL query?

Comment: @200_success, its the same as in the statemenrt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COALESCE(…, …, 2147483647)` will never return `NULL`.  Furthermore, `MIN(…)` will only return `NULL` when all of its inputs are `NULL`.

Assuming that every `NewPrice` and every `Price` is at most 2147483647, the following query should be equivalent.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
     , ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(NewPrice, Price)), 0)
    FROM MerchantsProducts
```

Comment: What if NewPrice or Price or both will NULL? Will it work?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 1):

## Vertical Space

Any time I see a horizontal scrollbar, I start to ask myself where I can use more newlines. I would reformat your query like this to make it easier to read:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Products],
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(MP.NewPrice, MP.Price, 2147483647)),0) = 2147483647
        THEN 0
        ELSE ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(MP.NewPrice, MP.Price, 2147483647)), 0)
    END AS [Minimum Price]
FROM MerchantsProducts MP
```

I personally find it mush easier to edit a query if I can see the entire thing without having to scroll.

I also took the liberty of adding column aliases, to prevent `(No Column Name)` potentially being returned.

## An alternate approach

As far as I can tell, this should be slightly more efficient than the answer given by 200_success.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Products],
    MIN(COALESCE(NewPrice, Price, 0)) AS [Minimum Price]
FROM MerchantsProducts
```

Looking at the execution plan generated by these simple tests reveals that this method doesn't have the Compute Scalar step, which makes it that little bit more efficient. when I say a little bit, I mean it. You probably won't notice any difference unless you are running the query against multiple hundreds of thousands of records.

Testing my approach:

```
 WITH TEST(newprice,price, count) AS
 (
    SELECT
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(1 AS INT)
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        count+1
    FROM TEST
    WHERE count < 1000000
)

SELECT 
    MIN(COALESCE(MP.NewPrice, MP.Price,0)) AS [Minimum Price]
FROM TEST MP

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Testing 200_success' approach:

```
WITH TEST2(newprice,price, count) AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(1 AS INT)
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        CAST(((2000 + 1) - 1) * RAND() + 1 AS INT),
        count+1
    FROM TEST2
    WHERE count < 1000000
)

SELECT 
    ISNULL(MIN(COALESCE(NewPrice, Price)), 0) AS [Minimum Price]
FROM TEST2 MP

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

If you have already altered the query to use 200_sucess' approach then I would leave it as is, unless you regularly run the query against very large data sets (100000+ records).